# SSL certificate file type

Tags: ssl-certificate, file-format, pfx

Bit of a silly question, but:

What kind of file(s) do you get when you buy an SSL certificate from a trusted CA?

Is there a .pfx file?

I'm working on a small tool to manage SSL certificates, but I'm not sure exactly what kind of certificates I'll be dealing with besides the self-signed ones that I create myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

.pfx file extension is one. The below text from IBM has some indepth information.

> **Certificate file types**
>
> Certificates and keys are stored in several types of files.
>
> Files that store certificates and keys can have the following formats:
>
> **.pem**
>
> A privacy-enhanced mail file, which has a file extension of .pem, begins and ends with the following lines:
>
> `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`
>
> `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`
>
> A privacy-enhanced mail format supports multiple digital certificates, including a certificate chain. If your organization uses certificate chaining, use this format to create CA certificates.
>
> **.arm**
>
> A file with an extension of .arm contains a base-64 encoded ASCII representation of a certificate, including its public key, but not its private key. An .arm format is generated and used by the IBM® Key Management utility. Specify this format to extract a self-signed certificate from the machine on which the self-signed certificate was generated to the machine that will use the self-signed certificate as the CA certificate.
>
> **.der**
>
> A file with an extension of .der contains binary data. This format can be used only for a single certificate, unlike a file with a privacy-enhanced mail format, which can contain multiple certificates. Specify this format to extract a self-signed certificate from the machine on which the self-signed certificate was generated to the machine that will use the self-signed certificate as the CA certificate.
>
> **.pfx (PKCS12)**
>
> A PKCS12 file, which has an extension of .pfx, contains a certificate (CA-issued certificate or self-signed certificate) and a corresponding private key. Use this format to transfer the contents of a keystore to a separate machine. For example, you can create and install a certificate and private key using key management utility, export the certificate and key to a PKCS12 file, then import the file into another keystore. This format is also useful for converting from one type of SSL implementation to a different implementation. For example, you can create and export a PKCS12 file using the IBM Key Management utility, then import the file on another machine using the OpenSSL CertTool utility.

The text above is a verbatim copy from [IBM Eclipse Help](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itim.infocenter.doc%2Fcpt%2Fcpt_ic_security_ssl_oview_ftypes.html).

Comment: P7B is another not mentioned in the link

Comment: +1. I hope you don't mind my edit. Additionally, `.p12` and `.pfx` are interchangeable file extensions. Yet more, `.key` generally contains only the private key, while `.crt` contains only a public key (the certificate itself).

Comment: @jweyrich: And based on my experience today, I think .cer is equivalent to .crt

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it looks like I'll only have to support .pfx files, since I need a private key (and those seem to be the only files that have one embedded)

Comment: @Cameron: both of your assertions are correct. `.crt` and `.cer` are also interchangeable. `.p12` is the best choice IMO, but you can also just concat your `.crt` and `.key` if you don't want a password-protected file. However, this imposes a limitation when importing the certificate in your browser for authentication.